# Trouble serving static files in Sinatra

Tags: css, ruby, static, sinatra

I found similar questions and followed the answers, but I am having no luck. 
I am trying to serve a CSS file to some of my pages using Sinatra, but it doesn't work for all pages.

I have a public folder at the same level as my "app.rb". The public folder structure is as follows:

```
public
  -css
  -images
  -js
```

In my app.rb, I just have one line like so:

```
set :public_folder, "public"
```

In my layout, I use:

```
href="/public/css/main.css"
```

It works for some pages like my index and about page, but once I dive deeper into my views, it doesn't work. I can get it to work if I manually set routes, but I don't want to end up doing that for all future views I add. This is what I do to get it to work:

```
change to href="/css/main.css"

get "/css/main.css" do
  redirect "/main.css"
end
get "/posts/css/main.css" do
  redirect "/css/main.css"
end
```

All the views use the same layout with the same url for the css file, when I go deeper into the views, the folders get added to the beginning of the css url which is why I added a route for it. Is there a way around this? Still new to this :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one, I don't believe you need the 'public' in your layout file.

```
href="/css/main.css"
```

Secondly, I recommend using scss/sass for styling. You just keep the .scss file within your primary /views directory.

```
app.rb
- views
 - index.haml/html
 - style.scss
```

In your .rb app file:

```
get '/style.css' do
  scss :style
end
```

Then, in your view:

```
href="/style.css"
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Alternatively, check out my Sinatra Starter on github! https://github.com/kunalbhat/sinatra-starter

Comment: thanks! I am using a modified bootstrap css file, is it as simple as just changing the file extension?

Comment: Sort of. Sass is a precompiler, which allows you a lot more styling power over normal css. Check it out: http://sass-lang.com/. You will also need to gem install sass.

Comment: I actually ended up finding out that I didn't need to specify the public folder named "public" because it is set by default. I must have messed up the path when setting it manually. Once I removed that, it worked.